Reference for proof of stability of almost linear systems
In Ordinary Differential Equations and Stability Theory by David Sanchez, he gives criteria for classifying spiral points and nodes and saddle points of a nonlinear system in terms of a linear system. He omits the proof. Where can I find a proof of these statements?
It's not in the book "Nonlinear Ordinary Differntial Equations" by Jordan and Smith.
